# Autofac : Questions about OnActivating and OnActivated

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have just started looking into using Autofac, and came across the Lifetime events `OnActivating` and `OnActivated`.

Now, I have read the Autofac documentation [HERE](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/events.html?highlight=onActivated#onactivating)

but it raises some questions on the difference between the two and their use.

Confusing points are:

1. The above docs say `OnActivated` is raised "once a component is fully constructed". So, to me that implies for `OnActivating` the component is NOT fully constructed, otherwise why bother mentioning it just for this event. If that is to be believed then how come you can change properties, and call methods on the instance (via the IActivatingEventArgs.Instance property)  if it is not ready?
2. The docs say for `OnActivating` that it is "raised before the component is used". Does "used" mean before any Resolve method passes the component out to client code?
3. Is the `OnActivated` event also raised BEFORE the component is "used"? The docs say nothing on this, but choose to mention it for the `OnActivating` event.

Would someone give a better account of when to use each event?

Comment: Well, I would ask my debugger to get the answers

Comment: What makes you think you need to use **either** event? I've not used either of them in my many years of work with Autofac.

Comment: @mjwills, I would like to use them to call a method on the component before the component is served out to the client code. I am aware there is an IStartable interface that could do this but I don't want to implement this on my domain classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OnActivated` event is fired when the whole component graph is fully build whereas the `OnActivating` event is fired when the component is build.

Let suppose we have this graph

[image]

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent(Child1 child1, Child2 child2, Child3 child3) { }
}
class Child1
{ }
class Child2
{
    public Child2() { }
}
class Child3
{
    public Child3(Child2 child2) { }
}
```

The event order will be :

```
Parent.preparing
Child1.preparing
Child1.activating
Child2.preparing
Child2.activating
Child3.preparing
Child2.preparing
Child2.activating
Child3.activating
Parent.activating
Child1.activated
Child2.activated
Child2.activated
Child3.activated
Parent.activated
Parent.release
Child3.release
Child2.release
Child2.release
Child1.release
```

Here is the code to trace these events :

```
public static class RegistrationExtensions
{
    public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TActivatorData, TRegistrationStyle> 
        Trace<TLimit, TActivatorData, TRegistrationStyle>(this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TActivatorData, TRegistrationStyle> registration)
    {
        return registration.OnPreparing(e => { Console.WriteLine($"{e.Component.Activator.LimitType.Name}.preparing"); })
                           .OnActivating(e => { Console.WriteLine($"{e.Component.Activator.LimitType.Name}.activating"); })
                           .OnActivated(e => { Console.WriteLine($"{e.Component.Activator.LimitType.Name}.activated"); })
                           .OnRelease(e => { Console.WriteLine($"{e.GetType().Name}.release"); }); ;
    }
}
```

The `preparing` event is fired before the instance is being created. You can provide new parameter for the activation process.
The `activating` event let's you change the instance with the `ReplaceInstance` method. It is usefull if you want to mock or do any interception with the object.
The `activated` event is really uncommon and you will almost never use it.
The `release` event is fired when the associated lifetime scope is disposed

In your case if you want to call a method to initialize your object you should use the `activating` event.